# remove special character

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I used this code for remove special character from text box.

```
$profile = $partner['profileurl'];
                                $profile = str_replace(' ', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('_', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('.', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('!', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('@', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('#', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('$', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('%', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('^', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('&', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('*', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('(', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace(')', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('=', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('+', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('?', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('/', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('<', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('>', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('|', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('`', '-', $profile);
                                $profile = str_replace('~', '-', $profile);

                                $profile = strtolower($profile);
                                                                ?>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                     <input type="text" id="profileurl" name="profileurl" value="<?php echo $profile; ?>" title="Profile Url" class="input-text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

But it have lot's of special charecter also i need to remove white space at end of the string.

I used `rtrim` function but first `$profile = str_replace(' ', '-', $profile);` i used this so both are conflicted first condition only working rtrim not working

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$profile = $partner['profileurl'];

$replace = array(' ', '_', '.', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '=', '+', '?', '/', '<', '>', '|', '`', '~');

$profile = strtolower(str_replace($replace, '-', trim($profile)));
```

You need to do this process in the proper steps; trim whitespace, replace chars, then lowercase. Here's a cleaned up version that doesn't call str_replace a dozen times, you can pass it an array of characters to replace.